# JavaFX defining inner class in FXML

Tags: java, class, javafx, fxml

Using NetBeans. I need help with the syntax for defining an inner class in FXML file.

Example class where Bar is inner class of Foo:

```
public class Foo {
    //... Foo stuff
    public class Bar {
        //... Bar stuff
    }
}
```

In the FXML file I want to use outer and inner classes. outer class Foo is recognised but inner class comes up with "Class does not exist:Foo.Bar".

Sample FXML:

```
<?import customcontrol.*?>
 <Region>
       <Foo name="thebigfoo" />        
       <Foo.Bar name ="inner"/>
 </Region>
```

P.S this is first post so I hope question formatting was correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the inner class as static class (not associated with Foo's instance):

```
public class Foo {
    //... Foo stuff
    public static class Bar {
        //... Bar stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: changed to static and still says class does not exist.